# SQL: UPDATE Without WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Would updating 1 million records without specifying the WHERE clause be quicker than specifying it?

```
UPDATE test
SET col1 = 'somevalue';

UPDATE test
SET col1 = 'somevalue'
WHERE col2 > 0;
```

Apologies for the noob question, logically I think is quicker without specifying it as it would not check where the condition meets, however, it could also mean that it will skip updating a row where the condition doesn't meet.

Is there an online tool that I can test speed with sample data.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: My guess is that it would depend on the number of rows matching the condition, whether it's indexed and the cost of writing data. If the where would filter say a 1000 rows using an index and apply update to them only it should be much faster. In any case, removing the where changed the meaning of the query.

Comment: What is important for the exercise. That the condition is met? Or that the query runs asap. I guess that 99% of the cases you will want to update only the rows that you need. Performance is secondary compared to consistency of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it depends. If only 10 out of the 1 million records met the condition and the condition has a solid index, then that is much faster than updating everything.